# I have multiple Home folders over several hard drives. I need to understand what I did wrong?

Tags: fstab, fdisk, home

I am running ParrotOS on an old MacPro. I have 3 SSD's and 1 HDD. I was trying to move my Home folder to the HDD. Doesn't that seem like the right thing to do?

When I run `fdisk -l` I only see three of my drives. I can deal with the missing drive later, as I may have a bad drive installed?

My problem is that it appears I have two home folders and it seems like I have somehow attached my drives to mount and media?

```
sudo fdisk -l        
Disk /dev/sdb: 111.79 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Disk model: SanDisk SDSSDA12
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xd337ed20

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 234441647 234439600 111.8G e8 unknown


Disk /dev/sda: 111.79 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Disk model: PNY CS900 120GB 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 6157174E-9DFB-D245-91E1-417891582537

Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       4096    618495    614400  300M EFI System
/dev/sda2     618496 150890415 150271920 71.7G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  150890416 234436544  83546129 39.8G Linux swap


Disk /dev/sdc: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: Hitachi HUA72101
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa14d0e48

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 1953525167 1953523120 931.5G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/mapper/luks-b6c8a5e1-b114-4450-ba66-00863e687e43: 111.77 GiB, 120016297984 bytes, 234406832 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

```
sudo blkid   
[sudo] password for warloxian: 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="b6c8a5e1-b114-4450-ba66-00863e687e43" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="d337ed20-01"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="Home" UUID="bbd9b199-b257-4e78-8524-4b12a8014855" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="a14d0e48-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="8039db30-fce5-4abe-9541-506a072a4b17" UUID_SUB="bd5de73a-5a95-4ee7-94c2-6447152c238c" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="btrfs" PARTUUID="862d307e-41eb-da40-a6e9-4b44740fd09d"
/dev/sda3: UUID="cd0170f4-8c2c-4bd9-a214-e17a7e8388ca" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="9f53be39-1528-8040-9755-272e58e2fe2e"
/dev/sda1: LABEL_FATBOOT="NO_LABEL" LABEL="NO_LABEL" UUID="756B-7FB3" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="a640ed42-891d-3149-b0cb-a24b29b398c6"
/dev/mapper/luks-b6c8a5e1-b114-4450-ba66-00863e687e43: LABEL="DANGEROU$" UUID="6be0ef1c-3491-4763-9325-f7974c071289" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
```

```
sudo lsblk                       
[sudo] password for warloxian: 
NAME                                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sda                                             8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk  
├─sda1                                          8:1    0   300M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2                                          8:2    0  71.7G  0 part  /
└─sda3                                          8:3    0  39.8G  0 part  [SWAP]
sdb                                             8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk  
└─sdb1                                          8:17   0 931.5G  0 part  /home
sdc                                             8:32   1 111.8G  0 disk  
└─sdc1                                          8:33   1 111.8G  0 part  
  └─luks-b6c8a5e1-b114-4450-ba66-00863e687e43 253:0    0 111.8G  0 crypt /mnt/6be0ef1c-3491-4763-9325-f7974c071289
sr0                                            11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

```
sudo mount                                     
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=18934000k,nr_inodes=4733500,mode=755,inode64)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=3796040k,mode=755,inode64)
/dev/sda2 on / type btrfs (rw,noatime,nodiratime,compress=zstd:3,ssd,discard,space_cache=v2,autodefrag,subvolid=256,subvol=/@)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,inode64)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k,inode64)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=30,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=27228)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
ramfs on /run/credentials/systemd-sysusers.service type ramfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
ramfs on /run/credentials/systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service type ramfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
ramfs on /run/credentials/systemd-sysctl.service type ramfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,noatime,inode64)
/dev/sda1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,noatime,nodiratime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/mapper/luks-b6c8a5e1-b114-4450-ba66-00863e687e43 on /mnt/6be0ef1c-3491-4763-9325-f7974c071289 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,x-gvfs-show)
/dev/sdb1 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime)
ramfs on /run/credentials/systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service type ramfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/debug/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=3796036k,nr_inodes=949009,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1003,inode64)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1003)
portal on /run/user/1000/doc type fuse.portal (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1003)
```

```
cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device; this may
# be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if
# disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=756B-7FB3                            /boot/efi      vfat    defaults,noatime,nodiratime 0 2
#UUID=8039db30-fce5-4abe-9541-506a072a4b17 /home          btrfs   subvol=@home,defaults,noatime,nodiratime,autodefrag,discard,compress=zstd 0 2
UUID=cd0170f4-8c2c-4bd9-a214-e17a7e8388ca swap           swap    defaults,noatime,nodiratime,discard 0 0
tmpfs                                     /tmp           tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/bbd9b199-b257-4e78-8524-4b12a8014855 /mnt/bbd9b199-b257-4e78-8524-4b12a8014855 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=Home%2FStorage 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/6be0ef1c-3491-4763-9325-f7974c071289 /mnt/6be0ef1c-3491-4763-9325-f7974c071289 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
UUID=bbd9b199-b257-4e78-8524-4b12a8014855 /home         ext4     defaults                   0 2
UUID=8039db30-fce5-4abe-9541-506a072a4b17 / btrfs subvol=@,defaults,noatime,nodiratime,autodefrag,discard,compress=zstd,noauto 0 1
```

```
ls -ld 
drwxr-xr-x 33 warloxian warloxian 4.0K Feb 15 09:18 .
```

Comment: "My problem is that it appears I have two home folders and it seems like I have somehow attached my drives to mount and media?" – No firm data in your post indicates this. Not that I don't believe you, my point is the information you posted is not enough in the context of your problem. [Edit]ing and adding the output of `mount`, `lsblk` and `cat /etc/fstab` to the question will be a good start. Plus `ls -ld` that actually shows the two home directories (and maybe "mount and media", whatever this means). Also: what exact command(s) did you use when "trying to move your Home folder to the HDD"?

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski if you look at cat etc/fstab you'll see it shows a home drive as btrfs and a home with ext4. I am sorry I am not good at recording the commands I use to do anything, but I am learning. I will start documenting what steps I take to help with troubleshooting problems. I am still learning. I have posted those outputs

Comment: "it shows a home drive as btrfs and a home with ext4" – The former is commented out; `#` starts a comment. The latter is not commented out, this is the entry that matters. Nothing mentions a location named `mount` or `media`, so I don't know what you mean by "somehow attached my drives to mount and media". Note `blkid` does not agree with `lsblk`+`mount`: at least `sdb` and `sdc` swapped places. This may happen when you reboot; and you did reboot, right. But this is only an incoherence of the question. I don't know what the *actual* problem is. Is something wrong with your `/home` now? What?

Comment: I feel kind of stupid. I forgot that I commented it out. And yes I did reboot. Sorry. Important lesson is look at the basics before getting carried away. Thanks for your time